# windows 8 pro system disk reading error

Tags: windows-8

My son accidently upgraded the system to windows 8.1pro then after some time while it was updating he switched the laptop off.  Now when I restart the laptop, it comes with the dialog error in disk reading: press tab+alt+del to restart.  I did it many times but it shows the same.  What should I do?

Comment: Those darn kids....

Answer (score 2):

If you have the original installation media, use it to reinstall and repair. You  might be able to order installation media from the computer manufacturer.

If you do not have installation DVD's, you *might* be able to start in Safe Mode and use Windows 8 Recovery, http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/repair-recovery-help#repair-recovery-help=windows-8&v1h=win8tab1. Windows 8 should attempt to start in Safe Mode if startup is interrupted two or three times, such as by attempting to start and holding the power button for five seconds. This is not the best way to do it, but is simplest to describe here. There is a chance that the aborted upgrade destroyed the recovery partition, however.

From your limited description, you might need assistance from someone more familiar with computers. If purchased from a retailer, you might get help there (e.g. Best Buy's *Geek Squad*).

At the very worst, you could install another OS, such as Linux, though some of your Windows applications may not work, even in Wine (Linux Windows emulator).

If you do need to use installation media, you will probably need to adjust UEFI ("BIOS") to enable booting from "legacy" devices; check you computer manufacturer's web site for details.